# Least Squared constrained for Rototranslation

Tags: optimization, matrix, rotation

I want to detect the best rototraslation matrix between two set of points.
The second set of points is the same of the first, but rotated, traslated and affecteb by noise.
I tried to use least squared method by obviously the solution is usually similar to a rotation matrix, but with incompatible structure (for example, where i should get a value that represents the cosine of an angle i could get a value >1).

I've searched for the Constrained Least Squared method but it seems to me that the constrains of a rototraslation matrix cannot be expressed in this form.

In this PDF i've stated the problem more formally:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3185608/minquad_en.pdf

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: What you will need here is "Principal Component Analysis".

Apply this to both sets of points centered at their respective centers of mass.  The PCA will effectively give you a rotation matrix for each aligned to the data set principal components.  Multiplying the inverse matrix of the original set by the new rotation will give you a matrix that takes the old (centered) set to the new.  Inverse translations and translations can similarly be applied to the rotation to create a homogeneous matrix that maps the one set to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The book [PRINCE, Simon JD. *Computer vision: models, learning, and inference.* Cambridge University Press, 2012.](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf)
 gives, in Appendix "B.4 Reparameterization", some info about how to constrain a matrix to be a rotation matrix.

It seems to me that your problem has also a solution based on SVD: see the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) also described by Olga Sorkine-Hornung and Michael Rabinovich in 
 [*Least-Squares Rigid Motion Using SVD*](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf) and, more practically, by Nghia Kien Ho in [*FINDING OPTIMAL ROTATION AND TRANSLATION BETWEEN CORRESPONDING 3D POINTS*](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671).